# Scale with custom snapping increment

Tags: modeling, texturing, scripting, uv, snapping

I'm making models with pixel art textures, the models themeselves are made up of cubes. The problem is that when the cubes are scaled they are not the proper size to be used with pixel art so either the pixels get stretched or cropped. I know that I can hold CTRL while scaling the cubes to make the snap but this is done in increments of 1. Is there a way to change this value? If there is no built in solution, is there a way to do this by script?

Comment: Use another object (an empty for instance) and set a driver on scale linked on its location (either x, y or z)

Comment: @lemon Can you please elaborate? I'm relatively new to blender :)

Comment: That's a nice solution. @VinnieH01, I'll explain it if it's still relevant.