# Snap to Increment while Scaling

Tags: transforms, snapping

**Introduction**

Hi there,

I'm using blender 3.6.4, using manjaro linux.

When I move the default cube around in a new project, it doesn't snap to anything, when I go into the top bar and enable snapping with `snap to increment` then when I move the object it's origin snaps to the 3d grid (steps of 1 unit).

At this point if I start scaling an object there is no snapping as well, so I went up to the snap menu and then made it affect scaling, when I now scale an object it snaps, but it snaps in `0.1` increments, which is unexpected since I thought it would scale to the grid lines like how the snapping with the move tool works.

**Question**

I was wondering how I can enable `increment snapping` for the scale tool and have it snap to grid lines (1 unit).

**What I've tried**

- I've found this [article](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-snapping-scale-objects-to-grid-increments/517635) which seems to have the same problem, but no one found an answer
- [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164948/how-to-scale-by-increment) seems to be an answer following it just increments in `0.1` units in my situation
- [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78567/scale-with-custom-snapping-increment) question seems to have snapping working to 1 unit (which is my goal), but is 6 years old, so maybe the way it works has changed since then

Comment: I do hope someone can answer this, I've never managed to get Snap to Increment to work intuitively, if at all. For precision work I wind up constructing my own jigs, faces deleted for visibility, and snap to vertices. That works very reliably for me.

Comment: I don't know whether this answer gives any clues? (I haven't read right through it): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/how-to-change-the-snapping-increment-in-different-units?rq=1